# SAS sum by group

Tags: sas, sum

I have a follow up tho this question:

[SAS, sum by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032292/sas-sum-by-group)

Since I need to group by more than one variable, I add the variable accordingly. I also do not need the last row, that is why I comment it. However, the variable sum_by_var1 is increasing within the group. But I want it to be the total sum of the group for each element in the group.

```
data new2;   
   set have;       
   by var1 var_new; 
   retain sum_by_var1;
   if first.var1 then do; sum_by_var1=0; end;
   sum_by_var1 + var3;
   *if last.var1 then do; output; end;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and code to run and answer to your question will be quick.

Comment: Your posted code cannot run.  Because you only commented out the first of three statements on a line you have an `end;` statement with no corresponding `do` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want an aggregate result associated with each row in the group, when a 'test' computation be someone else could find the 'sum' incorrect because your output discards the last row of the group.

In DATA Step you can use a DOW loop to compute a group statistic, followed by a second loop to apply that result to each row in the group.

Example:

```
data have;
input var1 var2 $ var3;
datalines;
1 a 3
1 a 4
1 a 3
2 b 5
2 b 3
3 c 1
;
run;

data want;
  * compute some aggregate result;
  do until (last.var1);
    set have;
    by var1;
    sum_var3_over_var1 + var3;
  end;

  * apply result to each row in group;
  do until (last.var1);
    set have;
    by var1;
    if not last.var1 then OUTPUT;  * discard some detail data;
  end;

  label sum_var3_over_var1 = 'Caution, this result may not appear correct';
run;
```

Result:

The result you 'want' is confusing

- The `var1=1` group had 3 rows to start, and there are 2 rows in output.
  The sum disagrees with what is visible because the last row of the group was discarded.
- The `var1=2` group had 2 rows to start, and there is 1 row in output.
  The sum disagrees with what is visible because the last row of the group was discarded.
- The `var1=3` group had 1 row to start, and there are **no** rows for the group in output.
  There is no row because the last row of the group was discarded.  When a group has only one row, that row is the last row (and the first row).

[image]

Comment: I end up with an empty dataset, even after the first step only

Comment: Not sure why you are getting empty result.  I've updated my answer with the data from the original question you referenced.  Also, did you get a useable answer from your original question and did you follow up by mark which response was the answer and most useful to you ?